# Non PnP driver as plug-n-play

Tags: drivers, plug-and-play

Since Windows 8 Device-manager doesn't show non plug and play drivers; Is is possible to trick windows into treating them as PnP drivers?

Comment: Its physically not possible to treat a device that does not have a PnP driver  as a PnP device.  That is the entire point of a PnP driver is to provide that functionality.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't need the **"device"** to have that functionality at all! I just want windows to deal with the **"driver"** as if it would have been a PnP "driver" and list it or enumerate it among them.